# How to imshow() to show basis images for hadamard transformation in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have successfully written the MATLAB code for finding the n-order hadamard matrix.
Then I found the transpose of that matrix.
Then I found the basis images,

```
e.g., A(1,3)th basis image = hadamard_matrix(:,1)*hadamard_matrix(:,2)'
```

But whenever I try to print it using imshow() function in matlab, it shows just a completely dark image for all the basis images.

So what is the correct approach to show such basis images in matlab ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only reasonable explanation I can think of right now, is that your resulting matrix contains only of values smaller than, say, 0.05.

Instead of the default bounds 0 and 1, try other high/low values. For instance:

```
imshow(A,[min(min(A)) max(max(A))]);
```

Comment: You can also do `imshow(A,[])`, which automatically maps the min and max values to 0 and 1 respectively.  +1 though as I also believe what you described is happening too.

Comment: Thanks. Now I get it why my basis images were shown as dark images.

Comment: @rayryeng: interesting, didnt know that one.